# Understanding continuity in metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $x_0 \in X$ and $r>0$ a real number.

The open ball in X of radius r centred on $x_0$ is the set

$B_r (x_0)=\{x \in X : d(x,x_0) <r \}$

The notation if considering more than one metric on X is $B_r ^d (x_0)$

I have a proposition that says f is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $f\big(B_{\delta} ^{d_x} (x_0)\big) \subseteq B _{\epsilon} ^{d_y} \big(f(x_0)\big)$

What does this proposition mean?

Also I specifically do not understand what is meant by $f\big(B_{\delta} ^{d_x} (x_0)\big) \subseteq B _{\epsilon} ^{d_y} \big(f(x_0)\big)$

Comment: Does the superscript $d_x$ indicate the metric on $X$?

Comment: Yeah it does indicate the metric on X

Comment: It means that all points in the open ball of radius $\delta$ around $x_0$ get mapped into the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition is essentially saying that $f$ is continuous at a point iff for any ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $f(x_0)$ in the codomain, there exists a ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x_0$ in the domain so that that its image is contained in the $\epsilon$ ball in the target.

It's just like the delta epsilon definition of continuity condition but with balls.

As an example consider the identity map from $f:X\to X$. If I take some epsilon ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $f(x_0)$ which in the notation you used would be $B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$, there should be some radius $\delta$ around the point $x_0$ that I can consider in the preimage so that all the points $x$ within $\delta$ of $x_0$ i.e. $x\in B_{\delta}(x_0)$ will be mapped to a point within $\epsilon$ of $f(x_0)$ i.e. $d(f(x), f(x_0))<\epsilon$. This is what is meant by $f(B_{\delta}(x_0))\subseteq B_{\epsilon}(f(x_0))$. But since $f$ is the identity map, all we need to do is define a radius less than $\epsilon$ in the domain and we are guaranteed that every point will be mapped to an image within $\epsilon$ of $f(x_0)$ since we are just  mapping a smaller ball into a larger ball. We can see that according the your definition this is continuous at every point.

Hopefully this makes sense :)

Comment: @Al jabra hopefully this example helps

Comment: A comment on notation: Most authors write the open ball of radius r, centered at x ,as  $B(x,r)$ or, if necessary $B_d(x,r)$. Caution :We can have $B_d(x,r)=B_d(x',r')$ with $x\ne x'$ or $r\ne r'$ or both.Set theorists prefer $f"A$ (read "$f$ double-tick $A$") for $\{f(a): a\in A\}$ rather than $f(A)$ because a set can be both  a member and a subset of the domain of $f$.